# Recursive and RecursiveAll scopes not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, caml

I could clearly see the Recursive and RecursiveAll scopes are not getting the list of files under the sub folders. It's listing out files under the parent folder and just sub folder. but it's not looking in to the sub folders and getting the list of folders or files. Wondering what could be wrong.

Trying to access the files under a sharepoint library and its subfolders.
When i use

```
<View Scope=\"Recursive\">,
```

i am seeing the below error message.

{"Exception":"API Gateway encountered an error. Error Message:  Native service provider error. Code : 500. Request Details: Service - XXXXXXXXXX, Operation - /sites/XXXXXXXX/cm/_api/web/, Invocation Time:10:56:39 AM, Date:Dec 15, 2019,  Client IP - XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, User - Default and Application:null"}

When i use

```
<QueryOptions><ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll' /> 
</QueryOptions>:
```

i could see no error. It's listing out files under the parent folder and just sub folder. but it's not looking in to the sub folders and getting the list of folders or files.

Comment: Hi, your question is pretty vague. It misses some context and examples. So; what's your question? What have you tried? And try to read; [ask].

Comment: edited the original post to add more details